# audio file comparison (java)

Tags: java

I'd like to make a comparison between two audio files based on their sample size (number of bits per sample)

I'm wondering if this code statement is correct:

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile1);
AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile2);

        // check sample size    
        if (clip1.getSampleSizeInBits() != clip2.getSampleSizeInBits()) {

        ...do something
              }
```

I get this error (repeated twice):
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getSampleSizeInBits()

What should I do?

Actually what I want to do is to check the difference , so if they have different sample size , the user should get a warning message.

Thanks for your help

Ulrike

Answer (score 2):

`getSampleSizeInBits` is a method of `AudioFormat`, not `AudioInputStream`. You can get the appropriate `AudioFormat` from the `getFormat` method of `AudioInputStream`, so the code should read:

```
clip1.getFormat().getSampleSizeInBits()
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I wanted to make a comparison based on other features like sample rate, channel, encoding , would I be right in writing only :
if (clip1.getFormat() !=  clip2.getFormat())
I mean the other features are part of the getFormat method...is that correct?

Comment: You still need to make the call to getFormat().
See the API for more details:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html
and:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html

Comment: @Carlos: Close.  You'd have to write if (!clip1.getFormat().matches(clip2.getFormat())).  AudioFormat does not have a valid equals method.